# How to redirect any folders within a subdirectory to a specific file using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I want to redirect any folder to a specific php file with the folder name as variable using htaccess, for example:

www.domain.com/subdirectory/folder1 redirects to www.domain.com/subdirectory/file.php?id=folder1

www.domain.com/subdirectory/folder2 redirects to www.domain.com/subdirectory/file.php?id=folder2

This should work if the folders have "/" at their end, for example,
www.domain.com/subdirectory/folder3/ redirects to www.domain.com/subdirectory/file.php?id=folder3

It will be better if I can put the .htaccess file in the subdirectory and get redirect rule according to it.

I created a .htaccess file with the following code while putting the file in the subdirectory:

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*)$ file.php?id=$1

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^folder(.*)$ file.php?id=$1`

use these i am not tested but it will be work.